# error occurs when executing the first row of linux bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash

We use notepad++ v6.4.5 to edit Bash scripts in Chinese Windows XP sp3. The coding format is UTF-8 without BOM. The first line source is as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

The source is executed on Centos 6.4 (Linux, LANG=en_US.UTF-8). However, we got the following error message :

```
for242.sh: line 1: 锘?!/bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

Could you help us? Thanks a lot. The Centos linux is configured as follows:

```
[root@centos64 ]# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a BOM at the start of the file anyway. This is standard on Windows. You can remove the UTF-8 BOM with dos2unix, if you have dos2unix version 6.0.0 or higher. If you do not have this version of dos2unix you can build it yourself. Get it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/

regards,

Comment: We tested a new bash file using "UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM"  and it works. It seems the "convert to UTF-8 without BOM" menu of notepad++ does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a CR on the end of that bangline. You need to convert the text file to Unix line endings.

Answer (score -1):

as you ftp your cmds to your linux machine, see if your ftp client has a "convert" feature.

Else use the relatively standard utility `dos2unix filename` to clean up your file and remove trailing carriage-returns.

Finally, are your sure there is really something installed as `/bin/sh`? You have tagged your question as bash, why not use `#!/bin/bash` To avoid confusion if you move your script to an environment that as a bourne shell (the true `/bin/sh`)?

IHTH

Comment: thanks. We have used **dos2unix** to convert the bash file and we also tested  **#!/bin/bash**. Errors occurs again.